# Coordinate Curves of a Parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, parametric

If I have a paraboloid

$z = 1 - x^{2} - y^2$

with a parametrization of

$\phi(r,\theta) = (rcos\theta, rsin\theta, 1 - r^2)$

I believe to prove $\phi$ as a parametrization I need $\phi$ to be *smooth* (continously differentiable) and I need $\phi_r \times \phi_\theta$ to *not* equal $0$ at all points.

I have done this for my homework, but my professor also asks us to  **describe coordinate curves of this parametrization**. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, polar coordinates always has a problem at $r=0$, so you'll have an issue at the vertex of of your paraboloid.

Coordinate curves are the images under $\phi$ of the curves $r=\text{constant}$ and $\theta=\text{constant}$.

Comment: I've updated my question to "how do you do this?", instead of "what is this?". If I had an example of a description of coordinate curves of a parametrization, I would know how to go about answering this problem.

Comment: Pick a few numbers, like $1$, $2$, $3$, and sketch the curves $\phi(1,\theta)$, $\phi(2,\theta)$, etc. Now do the same thing for $\theta$ values. Sketch $\phi(r,0)$, $\phi(r,\pi/2)$, $\phi(r,\pi/4)$, etc. I would bet your professor did some examples in class.

Comment: Not really this was more of a quote "critical thinking" exercise, but I think I got it. In the example, are $\phi_r$ and $\phi_\theta$ the general coordinate curves? This is based on the fact that they take the partial derivatives of the parametrization, each of which treats one variable as constant. Is this correct?

Comment: Those are the *tangent* vectors to the coordinate curves (at the appropriate point).